# What do you get when an iPod goes through a washing machine?

Tags: field-recording, m10

This is more of a share and tell story then an actual question.  I felt at least here this would be more appreciated then say... at my local coffee shop.  I'm sure those girls are just being polite when I ramble on about my hobby.

Like most people, my iPod has become a necessary part of life.  I need my music just about everywhere I go.  So when I was begrudgingly forcing myself to do laundry I happened to see my iPod sitting at the bottom of my washer.  I immediatley got a terrible heavy and sick feeling inside my stomach, like what happens when I watch Top Gun and Maverick is yelling "Goose! Oh No! No!"

I stuck it infront of a fan to dry it out, hoping that it may still work, when after an hour or so I hear this weirdest sound.  I get a bit freaked out because I've never heard it before in my apartment, and at first I couldn't tell where it was comming from.  When I did finaly realize it was my iPod, I resigned myself to the fact that this was the end and my iPod was officialy dying.

After sinking into a state of mourning for a few minutes, my natural instincts kicked in.  I grabed my ipod away from the fan, set it on the counter, grabed my trusty M10, and hit the shiny red button.

[soundcloud]soundcloud.com/auddity/as-the-ipod-dries[/soundcloud]

http://soundcloud.com/auddity/as-the-ipod-dries

I have a few ideas of how I'm going to implement this sound in a couple of my next projects.  It would also be fun to layer it in with some electircal sparks or maybe under a fire.  I also heard some nice static for tv channel changing in there.  What do you think of this sound? where would you want to use it?

Also, seeing as I don't recommend sacrificing your iPod to capture this, I'm willing to send out the original 24bit 96k recording to anyone who might find a good use for it.

Cheers.

P.S. Oh, the iPod still will play music, but the screen doesn't light up, and the control wheel might work if your rough with it.

Comment: Way to take advantage of an otherwise bad situation.

Comment: Seconded. Great reaction!

Comment: You're my sonic hero for the day.

Comment: This truly sounds quite cool :)

Comment: I'd love a copy of the sound!

Too late now, but a bag of rice is your friend when you've got your phone/iPod wet.

Comment: Also, I'll take a copy - doing a trailer where I want some nice glitchy/noisy impact sweeteners to sell the fact that the dudes getting beaten up are augmented. I think it'll fit right in as a layer.

Comment: @Auddity - I would appreciate a copy for the part at the end. It begins to sound like tiny creature noises, and I may find a use for that in a small project I am working on! Also, great thinking! A true sound designer. :D

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about the iPod, I know the feeling of it being your life - it's been the same for me too, but that sounds really cool and great instincts!  To me, this type of guerrilla situation is one of those exemplary moments of what makes sound effects recording so fun and rewarding.

I would love to procure a copy of the track for a sound effect trade, seeing that you are making the offer and I'd be willing to share something in return out of generosity for the offer.  My work finds me cutting computer sequences and radios/walkies a lot, and this static sounds vastly different than many recordings I've worked with, with that clean crisp hi-end and nice crackle.  If you're interest, shoot me an email at steve [at] stavrosound.com and we'll make something happen.

Happy recording, and happy repairs for the iPod!

Comment: I'm actually working on something now a small wireless video monitor is a character to the story that needs a signature sound, and this sound would be a great 'star' element for it I think.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, nice positive twist on a sad story.

Word on the street with regards to phones etc getting wet is to switch them off immediately, remove battery etc, and allow to dry off naturally, or in a bag of rice...

I'm loving that sound!

Answer (score 0):

my condolences! and i agree with the above posters as that is quite an exquisite sound. Also, i second the method of immediately powering off your newly-soaked device, removing the battery, and then submerging it in a bowl of dry uncooked rice for a few hours. thank you for sharing this sound with us

Answer (score 0):

depending on model you might be able to open it up so it dries further, then change the battery (likely bust from all that water) and restore it back to good health. certainly happened to my 1st gen Nano, which still keeps going, 6 years after purchase, and 3 after incident.